# bypass with JWT Token to enter the superset homepage/dashboard

Tags: apache-superset, flask-appbuilder

anybody have an update on how to bypass an user based on the JWT token into the Superset home page.

iam thinking that, it will validate the token user, who is recognised by google, azzure, facebook, etc.., then only authorize to the superset home page.